# Using progressive disclosures within JQuery Tools tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

Uh boy.. I have a client that wants EVERY bell and whistle going on their pages. Of course I am using JQuery; the original designers have supplied me with various bespoke scripts, however now the requirement list has grown and I have started modifying and adding to the original flat HTML.

The designers appear to have used JQuery UI - but frankly looking at all the functions I think it was over kill as they also supplied bespoke scripts for Cycle, Hover, Chosen. I didn't like the Tabs function as I could not seem to adapt it to the client's new requirements. So I turned to JQUery Tools for my tab solution - which works great.

HOWEVER I am trying to put progressive disclosures within my tabs - and they won't work at all! I have a bespoke script;

```
//OnClick
$('.sys_expandable li h3 a').click(function(){

    if( $(this).parent().parent().hasClass('active') ){
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active').find('div.sys_section').slideUp(200);        
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active').find('div.sys_section').slideDown(200);
    }

});
```

And the HTML;

```
<DIV class=PLACE id=PLACE1 title=tabs>
<UL class=tabs>
    <LI>
        <A href="#tabone">General Information</A>
    </LI>
    <LI>
        <A href="#tabtwo">Rentals</A>
    </LI>
    <LI>
        <A href="#tabthree">Referrals</A>
    </LI>
</UL>
</DIV>
<DIV class=pane id=tabone>
<DIV class=PLACE id=PLACE2 title=tabone >
    <P>
        <ul class="sys_expandable">
        <li class="sys_expandableContainer">
          <h3>
            Health Partners 
          </h3>
          <div class="sys_section"> 
            <p>
              Health Partners will take steps...
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="sys_expandable">
        <li class="sys_expandableContainer">

          <h3>
            East Wing external refurbishment
          </h3>
          <div class="sys_section">

            <p>
              The East Wing has been a ....
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </P>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class=pane id=tabtwo>
<DIV class=PLACE id=PLACE3 title=tabtwo>
    <P>
        Tab two
    </P>
</DIV>
</DIV>
 <DIV class=pane id=tabthree>
 <DIV class=PLACE id=PLACE4 title=tabthree >
    <P>
        Tab three
    </P>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

Can anyone see a conflict? I am pulling my hair out over this one!

Thanks in advance to anyone that has a clue.

Comment: PS. The same script works fine OUTSIDE of tabs. Go figure!

Comment: There is no hyperlink in section h3 of your lists (you select .sys_expandable li h3 a but there is no a in your example...). Could you please check?

Comment: Ah, you're right - I left out the beginning of the script;

$('.sys_expandable li h3').wrapInner('<a href="#na"></a>');
$('.sys_expandable div.sys_section').hide();

These are the lines that add the link.. Please remember I am loading JQuery and JQueryTools before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle with hyperlink added : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/5GwND/ .

Does it works as you want?

Comment: Ah, sadly no - but I want to thank you, as it was your instruction on JQueryTools Tabs that converted me from JQuery UI to Tools. Please see my response to Samuel on the above post as to everything that is loading.

Comment: I tried to fiddle a bit more and got a bit further;
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/5GwND/4/embedded/result/

Any more ideas?

Comment: You also have to embed your 3 tabs in a container. Here is the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/5GwND/17/ .

Comment: YESSSSSSS!!! Indeed it works a treat.. Now I just have to fit it in the CMS. That ought to be fun.. NOT! Thanks a million!